# What is purpose of 'else' block after try-except?

Tags: python, python-3.x

While learning python, I have read questions regarding my one but I could not get why such implementation is done by python.

**Case-1**: Exception is thrown & `sd` is set to 45

```
try:
    raise ValueError()
    sd = 45
except(OSError): 
    sd = 50
else:
    sd = 23
```

**Case-2**: Exception is handled by `except` & sd is set to 50

```
try:
    raise ValueError()
    sd = 45
except(ValueError): 
    sd = 50
else: 
    sd = 23
```

**Case-3**: No error is occurred then else will be executed & `sd` is set to 23

```
try:
    sd = 45
except(ValueError): 
    sd = 50
else: 
    sd = 23
```

We always wish that our code must work & if error is thrown it should be handled. But why `else` play role here that, if code in try block have no error then run this.

Please suggest if I misunderstood, missed or misdirected.

Comment: `try` are almost like if statements, so it normal to use `else` with it ,you put`'except` to handle specific errors

Comment: @timmy What to do to stop defining `sd` if exception is raised in previous code in try block. As per other references of language, try block handle exception (if exception occur) & must stop further code execution.

Comment: you can use `finally: sd=50` , you would normally want to assign a value for each error or `pass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend checking out https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html - There's an entire section on this:

> The try … except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception. ....

**@Edit** To elaborate on this - The point of `else` is when you do something that you think *might* error (like, opening a file that might not exist), you can put the code utilizing that file in the `else` statement rather than within `try`, allowing you avoid catching an exception not raised by your `try` statement (ie, what if something completely unrelated to opening the file broke in your usage of the file?)

Comment: Thanks you cleared what I missed! What to do to stop defining sd if exception is raised in previous code in try block. As per other references of language, try block handle exception (if exception occur) & must stop further code execution

Comment: Glad this helped - If you can, please "✔ Accept this answer". To answer your subsequent question, I recommend thinking about the problem slightly differently: Rather than trying to "stop defining sd", try unsetting it (check the `del` keyword out). If you're asking how to just exit the program, `sys.exit()` is what you're looking for.